# Angular 9 to 10 solution style tsconfig.json should be created before or after upgrade

Tags: angular10

I have upgraded my angular application from v9 to v10. tsconfig.base.json has not been created and also .browserlistrc

Can anyone help what is wrong with my approach?

Here is the steps i followed:

### global level:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g

npm cache clean --force

npm install @angular/cli@latest -g
```

### project folder level:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force

ng update @angular/material

npm install
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The migration to create `tsconfig.base.json` was removed because it caused unexcepted bugs. You can read about it here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/18478.